# Adding an extra JSON Object to the Web API Response

Tags: asp.net, json, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I need to attach an extra JSON object to my JSON response generated by the Web API Method. For example:

**My code now:**

```
[Route("api/getcomnts")]
public IHttpActionResult GetCommentsForActivity(string actid)
{
       List<Comment> cmntList = CC.GetAllComments(actid);
       return Ok(cmntList);
}
```

If the comments were successfully retrieved, I'd like to send:

> "status":"success"

**along with** the comments list that it already sends as the JSON Array.

or

> "status":"fail"

if the comments list is EMPTY. Is it possible to attach this extra JSON object named JSON to my already existing method?

This would make it very convenient for my client Android and iOS apps :)

**EDIT**

Or for a scenario such as this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/registeruser")]
    public IHttpActionResult RegisterUser(string name, string email, string password)
    {

        int stat = opl.ConfirmSignup(name, email, password);
        string status = "";
        if (stat == 0)
        {
            status = "fail";
        }
        else
        {
            status = "success";
        }
        return Ok(status);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return anonymous object with Web API.

```
    [Route("api/getcomnts")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCommentsForActivity(string actid)
    {
           List<Comment> cmntList = CC.GetAllComments(actid);
           var success = cmntList.Count() > 0 ? "success" : "success";
           return Ok(new { List = cmntList, success } );
    }

**EDIT:**

    [Route("api/getcomnts")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetCommentsForActivity(string actid)
    {
           List<Comment> cmntList = CC.GetAllComments(actid);
           string status = "";
           if(cmntList.Count()!=0)
           {
                status = "success";
           }
           else
           {
                status = "fail"; 
           }
           return Ok(new { List = cmntList, status } );
    }
```

Comment: I can not test it now but I think yes it will work, why not give it a try?

Comment: Hey mate it returns "{"string":"success"}" instead of {"status":"success"}. The word "status" is not coming

Comment: new { List = cmntList, status = success } can you try that.

Comment: No the previous example works, I edited and posted a new method in my question. This method just returns a "success" without the "status" part. Can you check the edit please? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get(string actid)
    {
        //sample..
        if (value == true)
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, getStatus("success"), JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
        else
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, getStatus("failed"), JsonMediaTypeFormatter.DefaultMediaType);
    }

    private object getStatus(string s)
    {
        var status = new { Status = s };
        return status;
    }
```